# Application not running, but dock thinks it is, so i can't quit/open it

Tags: macos, finder, dock

This has happened to multiple applications so far, i'm not sure what causes it, but it seems to happen after force quitting (sometimes).

First, you force quit it, and it does, but the dock shows that it is still open, but not responding. If you go to activity monitor, it does not show up. When you try to use the killall command by name, it tells you "No matching processes belonging to you were found". If you drag the file location into terminal, it still does not work. Deleting (using the rm command, as moving to trash does not work as finder claims the application is running) and reinstalling does not do anything, so i believe it has to do with the dock, or something else on the mac, not the application itself.

OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.3

Edit:

My guess as to what might've happened is the application quit, but the computer never got any indication that it did for whatever reason, so telling it to quit does nothing, but you're not allowed to open an already open application, so you can't open or close it.

Things that do not work:

Terminal : `killall Dock`

Terminal : `killall Finder`

Applescript : `tell application "(application name)" to activate`

Finder Menu : Relaunch

Comment: The answer is `pkill launchservicesd && pkill Dock`

Comment: I know this is an old closed question, but I encountered this today and in my case it was Terminal.app that got stuck, so I couldn't run commands within the affected user account, and relaunching the Dock and Finder didn't fix it.

In my case what I did was switched to another user account and ran `launchctl bootout user/$(id -u "${user}")` to logout the affected user, after logging back in the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problm with the Dock itself rather than the application. Try `killall Finder` in the Terminal which restarts the Finder and the Dock.

Comment: By looking through the package and running the linux file, i have managed to open the applications, however, the application is still shown as not responding in the dock as a new instance of the same application with the same name... It'd be great if i could get rid of that, it kinda annoys me...

Comment: I'm having the same issue...  since the process isn't running, Force Quit does nothing and the app doesn't show up in `ps aux` since it's not actually running.  Opening the "App.app" doesn't work since presumably Mac since it's already running. Opening "App.app/Contents/MacOS/app" directly DOES work, but then oddly I see two instance of the app in the Dock.  And just like you, `killall Finder` and `killall Dock` don't fix it either